# NMaster key from n secret key

Tags: key-derivation

I have to derive master key from N secret key. With the help of master key, i can collect all the secret keys which is used to derive master key.

key1, key2,..keyN ==> **single master key**

and

**single master key** ==> key1, key2,..keyN

is this even possible??

Comment: n=N? also, it's not n-secret key, it's n secret keys, I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are a number of different solutions.

One depends on a large random-looking, easily computable permutation $(\pi,\pi^{-1})$ on strings of $Nl$ bits. The master key is the $n$-bit string $\mathit{mk}$, the $i$th key share $k_i$ is an $l$-bit string, there are $N$ key shares and $0^{Nl-n}$ is a string of $Nl-n$ zeros. The concatenation of strings $x$ and $y$ is denoted by $x||y$. Then derive the key shares from the master key using $$k_1 || k_2 || \dots || k_N = \pi(\mathit{mk} || 0^{Nl-n}).$$
To recover the master key from the key shares, compute
$$\mathit{mk} || 0^{Nl-n} = \pi^{-1}(k_1 || k_2 || \dots || k_N).$$

This is secure for a random permutation, so it should also be secure for a random-looking permutation.

You can build a sufficiently large random-looking permutation using a Feistel construction, Luby-Rackoff and a random oracle.

If you want to be able to recover the master key from a subset of the key shares, you need to go to secret sharing. It should be possible to do this, but it is trickier and you don't get information theoretical security. Which probably isn't a problem. (The above permutation-solution doesn't get information theoretical security, either.)

Comment: Nice answer. Is there a scheme that gives information theoretical security?

Comment: I would not expect information theoretical security to be possible.